# "Autant s'y faire dès à présent"?

Tags: sens, indications-de-temps, comparatifs

I saw this in a book I'm reading:

> Demain, elle dépendrait à jamais d’un homme dont elle finirait par porter le nom. *Mme Thorn.* Autant s’y faire dès à présent.

I cannot make sense of that middle sentence. I see that “dès à présent” means *here and now*, and *se faire à* is *to get used to*.

Is it "So much to get used to right now" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Autant” here means “might as well”. I suppose it's probably short for “il vaut autant faire X” — it's just as worthwhile to do X.
(As worthwhile as what? As *not* do it, I guess. This sounds odd, but the same ellipsis takes place in English: Might as well do X as what? As not do it!)

Next, “dès [a certain time]” means from that time forward. So “dès à présent” means from this moment forward.

So one translation of the sentence might be:

> Might as well get used to it starting now.

Comment: Maybe _from now on_ would be a more idiomatic way to say this?

Comment: @Kii Equally idiomatic, says this native speaker, and almost equally good here, but I like mine slightly better :) But yup, no reason that couldn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the quite correct "autant commencer à s'y faire dès à présent" I suggest that the writer hasn't come up with the happiest form if we insist on "from one point on" as indicating a period of time for the action and not a point (to get used to sth, se faire à qqc); otherwise we must change the signification, that is consider that there is an other one ("se faire à quelque chose" serait alors "accepter ") and the author has possibly, inconsciously may be, "slipped towards that idea"; however defective writing seems to be the problem, not a far-fetched definition of "se faire à qqc".

Comment: There's nothing defective about the French.  I think just fail to fully understand it.

Comment: @petitrien (TLFi) : Se faire à. S'habituer, s'adapter à (quelqu'un ou quelque chose). La logique n'est pas bonne, le processus ne se réalise pas en un *point* du temps mais sur une période de temps. ex. La première bouchée de pain était amère ; je m'y suis fait et comme ça la seconde était potable. (ça ne va pas, il faut d'autres bouchées). Vous ne comprenez pas.

Comment: Autant se faire à cette dépendance dès à présent, voilà le sens, dépendance induite par le mariage et le changement de nom.  C'est parfaitement clair.

Comment: @petitrien Ne divertissez pas la question sur des points sans conséquence ; qu'importe ce à quoi il est question de se faire ? C'est évident ça et ça n'a rien à voir avec le changement. C'est le terme « dès à présent » en combinaison avec le verbe « se faire à qqc » qui ne convient pas.

Comment: "Dès à présent" ne convient pas avec "se faire à", c'est votre opinion, pas la mienne.  Il faut vraiment être très imbu de soi-même pour prétendre en faire une vérité générale comme vous le faites.  En plus, vous écrivez comme un pied : une bouchée pain potable.  Ridicule !

Comment: @petitrien Oui monsieur, une bouchée de pain potable; (TLFi) Qui n'est ni très bon ni franchement mauvais, qui est passable sans plus. Synon. acceptable.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une question de sens mais de style.

Comment: @petitrien Il faudrait que vous développiez ce point avec assez de soin pour que je m'y intéresse ; je ne fonde pas mes convictions sur les assertions en l'air de n'importe qui.